# In ggplot2 bar chart legend elements in wrong order and one player's bar colors are off

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the legend for the bar chart, the colors in the legend do not match the colors in the bars: They are out of order. For example, in the bar chart, the leftmost part of each bar, which is for Season 1 is yellow, but in the legend, the yellow color is for Season 8, so the legend's colors do not match the bar chart's.

In addition:

1. Each box in the legend has a black border. I would like those borders removed but the borders kept that are around the bars in the bar chart.
2. For Season 1,Koosman had zero wins, so no box is shown for it, thus the colors in the bar are out of step. Is there a way to adjust for that so Koosman's first box in his bar is the Season 2 color?

I checked the stackoverflow solutions, but did not see one that matched my situation. If one exists, I would appreciate it if you can share its link.

[image: Output]

**Dput for win_dfL**

```
structure(list(Pitcher = c("Jacob deGrom", "Jacob deGrom", "Jacob deGrom", 
"Jacob deGrom", "Jacob deGrom", "Jacob deGrom", "Jacob deGrom", 
"Jacob deGrom", "Tom Seaver", "Tom Seaver", "Tom Seaver", "Tom Seaver", 
"Tom Seaver", "Tom Seaver", "Tom Seaver", "Tom Seaver", "Dwight Gooden", 
"Dwight Gooden", "Dwight Gooden", "Dwight Gooden", "Dwight Gooden", 
"Dwight Gooden", "Dwight Gooden", "Dwight Gooden", "Jerry Koosman", 
"Jerry Koosman", "Jerry Koosman", "Jerry Koosman", "Jerry Koosman", 
"Jerry Koosman", "Jerry Koosman", "Jerry Koosman", "Sid Fernandez", 
"Sid Fernandez", "Sid Fernandez", "Sid Fernandez", "Sid Fernandez", 
"Sid Fernandez", "Sid Fernandez", "Sid Fernandez"), Season = c("S1", 
"S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", 
"S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", 
"S8", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S1", "S2", 
"S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8"), Wins = c(9, 14, 7, 15, 10, 
11, 4, 7, 16, 16, 25, 18, 20, 21, 19, 11, 17, 24, 17, 15, 18, 
9, 19, 13, 0, 19, 17, 12, 6, 11, 14, 15, 6, 9, 16, 12, 12, 14, 
9, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**ggplot2 Code**

```
win_dfL %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Pitcher, y=Wins, fill=Season)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", width = .85) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#A0522D",
                             "#FAD5A5",
                             "red",
                             "white",
                             "gray",
                             "#C04000",
                             "#FF7518",
                             "yellow")) +
  # Horizontal bar plot
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "the borders kept that are around the bars in the bar chart"? Do you mean one border around each complete bar and not between the colours within each bar? Or borders around each colour of each bar as shown in the plot in the question?

Comment: @Peter I mean a border "around each colour on each bar."

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
win_dfL %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Pitcher, y=Wins, fill=Season)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", width = .85, position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#A0522D",
                             "#FAD5A5",
                             "red",
                             "white",
                             "gray",
                             "#C04000",
                             "#FF7518",
                             "yellow")) +
  # Horizontal bar plot
  coord_flip() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA)))
```

[image]

`position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)` within geom_bar reverses the color sequence, and `guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA)))` gets rid of the borders in the legend.

Comment: For the Jerry Koosman bar, how were you able  to prevent the S1 (leftmost, first Season) part of the bar, which is zero, from appearing?

Comment: If you plot without coord_flip, the output is correct ( no wins for Jerry in S1) and the bar correctly consists of seven color only. If you flip the coordinates, the factor levels get reversed, so there suddenly is a S1 but no S8. By applying
guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA)))
you reverse the order again, S8 becoming S1 and thereby disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `fct_rev` from `forcats` package:

```
win_dfL %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Pitcher, y=Wins, fill=forcats::fct_rev(Season))) +
  geom_col()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#A0522D",
                             "#FAD5A5",
                             "red",
                             "white",
                             "gray",
                             "#C04000",
                             "#FF7518",
                             "yellow")) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify my instructions, I would like each color in the five bars in the bar chart (each but one has 8 colors) to have a black border. You, correctly, do not have a border around any of the items in the legend.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of `mutate` and `fct_rev` [fct_rev documentation](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_rev.html).

```
win_dfL %>%
  mutate(Season = fct_rev(Season)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Pitcher, y=Wins, fill=Season)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", width = .85) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#A0522D",
                             "#FAD5A5",
                             "red",
                             "white",
                             "gray",
                             "#C04000",
                             "#FF7518",
                             "yellow")) +  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And just for fun an additional version with the legend in season order and saving a bit of typing by using geom_col rather than geom_bar and stat  "identity"...

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
   
ggplot(win_dfL)+
    geom_col(aes(Wins, Pitcher, fill = fct_rev(Season)), width = 0.85, colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = paste0("S", 8:1),
                    values = c("#A0522D",
                               "#FAD5A5",
                               "red",
                               "white",
                               "gray",
                               "#C04000",
                               "#FF7518",
                               "yellow"))+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(colour = NA)))+
  labs(fill = "Season")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>